# Trouble printing out data of a nested vector in a template class (C++)

Tags: templates, vector, printing, iterator, nested

I'm having some trouble printing out the values of my nested vector. 
So I've got a template for a class with one of the protected variables being a nested vector. 
I tried using iterators as you can see, but running on visual studio 2015, there were no problems with the build just a horrible debugger window popped up!

Here is the template class in my header file:

```
template <class T> class experiment : public measurement <T> { 
protected:
std::vector < std::vector <T> > vdata; //declared the nested vector here
std::vector <T> verror; //another normal vector
public: 
experiment(int m);

void print() { //problem with print!
    using namespace std; //I've created my own namespace for the rest of my programme
    for (int i = 0; i != vdata.size(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k != vdata[i].size(); i++) {
            cout << "Value : " << vdata[i][k] << "  Error: " << verror[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Here is my main cpp

```
 #include <iostream>  
 #include <vector>
 #include "HeaderClass.h"
 using namespace test;
 using namespace std;

int main() {

experiment <double> exp(3); 
exp.print(); //code is perfectly fine until here

return 0;
```

}

I just can't see what's wrong. 
I hope you can help, thanks! :)

Comment: What does the debugger windows say? BTW your first snippet lacks a '}' and the nested for should be: for (int k = 0; k < vdata[i].size(); **k++** ) {...

Comment: Instead of `using namespace std;` use std::cout